# I cant delete a folder. Can anybody help?

Tags: xubuntu, delete

I unzipped a huge folder, it was taking ages and at the end it failed. Now I can't delete the folder i extracted when i try i get a message "deleting files... preparing..." but it doesn't delete the folder.

Comment: Do you tray `rm -rf /path_to_folder/folder_name`

Comment: As you're a reputation 13 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of it, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It probably *will* delete it but it will take a while to complete. But using `rm` can error out with a `-bash: /bin/rm: Argument list too long` where it reaches a kernel limit.

There is a VERY fast method: use "perl".

```
cd directory/
perl -e 'for(<*>){ unlink }
```

- [unlink](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/unlink.html): Deletes a list of files. On success, it returns the number of files it successfully deleted. On failure, it returns false and sets $! (errno):

I found that gem on [slashroot](http://www.slashroot.in/which-is-the-fastest-method-to-delete-files-in-linux); in comments someone stated the "stat" in there was not needed so I took the shorter one.

Be careful though that your execute this in the correct directory.

---

Because that 1st one is a bit obscure the other one seems sufficient too:

```
rsync -a --delete {emptydir}/ {foldertobeemptied}/
```

- create an empty dir ({emptydir}) and sync it with your folder ({foldertobeemptied})

Easier to understand and a little bit less quick than the perl version.

Also found on [slashroot](http://www.slashroot.in/which-is-the-fastest-method-to-delete-files-in-linux).

Comment: Rinz, Actually `rm` can fail due to the size of its arguments  i.e. argument list of `rm` being too long. .it is imposed by kernel itself..you can find the size with `getconf ARG_MAX`..i am not sure if it has anything to do with memory..

Comment: ah yes you are correct :)

Comment: @Rockloh: As you're a reputation 1 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**